# Laravel Orchid - unable to retrieve values from URL

Tags: laravel

I have an Orchid screen for displaying reports and want to display by month and year.

http://url.com/main/report/2022/01

I have this in my platform routes

```
 Route::screen('/main/report/{year}/{month}', DashboardReportScreen::class)
       ->name('platform.report');
```

How can I access year and month from within my screen file?

Inside my DashboardReportScreen, the query function looks like this:

```
public function query(): iterable
{
    print_r($year);
    // NULL RETURN
}
```

How can I access custom parameters in my URI from within my screen?

Comment: You should accept it as params of `query` method like `query($year, $month)`

Comment: thanks! that worked. I remember trying this before but not working. I think the only change i did was remove the ? in my {parameters?} in my platform routes

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments to the "query" function in your screen file as it is here https://orchid.software/en/docs/quickstart-crud/